# How to manipulate tfds.load() datasets correctly in tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am learning how to create a MNIST model from scratch in tensorflow 2.0 and Keras from a Udemy course.

So, I got the mnist dataset as follows

```
mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name = 'mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_dataset['train'], mnist_dataset['test']
```

and everything was fine, even I got 97% accuracy testing my model and I was happy.

The problem started when I tried to do something different from the course. I tried to print some examples from mnist_dataset using matplotlib `plt.imshow()` and I totally failed. Then I started some research and I got a solution, I needed to get the dataset like this:

```
mnist_dataset2 = tfds.load(name = 'mnist')
mnistt = mnist_dataset2['train']
```

where `mnistt` is the dataset I can manipulate and print using matplotlib.

So my question is as follows: where can I get information about types of tfds.load() you can get and how to correctly manipulate them as you want?  (and being somewhat extendible from a beginner in tensorflow like me).

Comment: just to clarify, the title says tf.load() but in fact i was talking about tfds.load() and i don't know if i mess up the the post. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, FTFY

Answer (score 1):

The main invocation of the `tfds.load` method contains everything you need:

```
mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name = 'mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

- `name="mnist"` -> you're specifiying the builder you want to use (mnist)
- `with_info=True` -> you're asking `tfds.load` to return the `info` object that contains **all you need to know** about the returned dataset
- `as_supervised=True` -> you're asking `tfds.load` to get only the elements of the dataset needed for a supervised learning task (the image and label pair).

Your first attempt of using `mnist_dataset` to get the data (to use with `matplotlib`) failed because as you can see from

```
print(mnist_info) #run me!
```

The dataset contains 2 different splits: `train` and `test`.

```
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
    name='mnist',
    version=1.0.0,
    description='The MNIST database of handwritten digits.',
    urls=['https://storage.googleapis.com/cvdf-datasets/mnist/'],
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'image': Image(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8),
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=10),
    }),
    total_num_examples=70000,
    splits={
        'test': 10000,
        'train': 60000,
    },
    supervised_keys=('image', 'label'),
    citation="""@article{lecun2010mnist,
      title={MNIST handwritten digit database},
      author={LeCun, Yann and Cortes, Corinna and Burges, CJ},
      journal={ATT Labs [Online]. Available: http://yann. lecun. com/exdb/mnist},
      volume={2},
      year={2010}
    }""",
    redistribution_info=,
)
```

Thus, the object returned by `tfds.load` is a **dictionary**:

```
{
   "train": <train dataset>,
   "test": <test dataset>
}
```

In fact, in the next line of the example, you extract the "train" and "test" datasets in this way:

```
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_dataset['train'], mnist_dataset['test']
```

From the `mnist_info` object, you can get every info you need to manipulate your dataset: the number of splits, the data type (e.g. "image" is a 28x28x1 image with dtype tf.uint8), etc...

Comment: i understand everything you say, then lets go to the problem:
- i am able to print some examples with the code below:
mnist_dataset2 = tfds.load(name = 'mnist')
mnistt = mnist_dataset2['train']

for mnist_example in mnistt.take(1):
    image = mnist_example['image']
    plt.imshow(image.numpy()[:,:,0].astype(np.float32))

...

Comment: but i am not able to print examples using mnist_dataset or mnist_train using the same code. as far i can understand, mnist_train and mnistt are a bit different 
mnist_train: <_OptionsDataset shapes: ((28, 28, 1), ()), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>
mnistt : <_OptionsDataset shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>
mnist_train

and i don't inderstand how to manipulate mnist_train to be able to print some examples usint plt.imshow()

Answer (score 0):

try this

`x_train, y_train = Next(iter(mnist_train))`

then plot `x_train`